# S3 battery not work after water damage

Tags: battery, water-damage

I dropped my S3 in water and the stock battery stopped working. I didn't know how to fix it (I tried drying it with a hair dryer but it did not work) so after comparing prices and discounts I bought a new [replacement battery](http://www.mpjbattery.com/battery-for-samsung/for-galaxy-s3-i9300.html) from MPJ and have used it for a month already.

It appears to work just as well as my stock battery. I don't know it's actual longevity but it works OK so far. Since I ordered from an official website, hopefully it's not a fake one...

I still want to fix the stock battery though, can anyone help me?

Comment: Using a hair dryer for that is, next to put it into the sun and after putting it into the microwave, one of the biggest mistakes for this task. There are plenty of better ways (including putting it in rice). As for "how to revive a dead battery", this isn't really an Android specific issue and thus not covered on this site, sorry.

Comment: Bowl of rice ftw will do the trick, but as @Izzy pointed out, classic! Someone here in Dublin lodged a complaint about Samsung S3 *exploding* when exposed to sun, Samsung execs panicked, flew over, to take it back to investigate, roped in help with fire brigade to investigate, transpires, that the guy actually microwaved the S3 *to dry out* after water exposure, when exposed in direct heat, shorted out the radio and "exploded"... got caught out in the end!!! There was a big thread on irish boards about it and had to publicly apologize for the uproar in the first! *true story bro*

Comment: Regarding the safety: Dispose of the dead battery. The li-ion part itself is sealed and probably unharmed, however there's also the charging/supervising circuit: That got soaked and due to the battery voltage, electrolytic corrosion set in and probably dissolved pcb paths already.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you can't. The charge/protection circuitry in the battery probably got damaged by the water, and you're done now.

Count yourself lucky that it was only a new battery that you needed and be happy.